# When requesting actions for a board I do not get checkItems added

Tags: api, trello

I am getting the actions for a Board using the Trello API. In the results, I get "updateCheckItemStateOnCard" when a checkItem is checked, but I do not get something like "checkItemAdded" when a checkItem is added to a checklist.

```
var parameters = {
    fields: 'all',
    since: self.lastUpdate
};
var path = '/boards/' + board.id + '/actions/';
Trello.get(path, parameters, getActions);
```

Is this a problem with the Trello API?
How can I get the actions when a checkItem is added to a checklist.

Note: I don't want to have to send this request to each card on the board. I asume that if I get "updateCheckItemStateOnCard" when a checkItem is checked, when requesting actions for a board, I should also get the action when a checkItem is added to a checklist.

Comment: the correct action type is `createCheckItem`, but there are some actions that are only sent through webhooks, but do not appear when you query the `/1/board|card/<id>/actions` endpoint. Don't know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Zapier and their tech support told me, that there does not seem to be an action addChecklistItemToCard.